# $f(x) = x\sin(1/x)$, $0 < x \le 1$, with $f(0) = 0$, is continuous on $[0, 1]$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How do I see that the function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x \sin(1/x) & 0 < x \le 1,\\
0           & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
is continuous on $[0, 1]$?

Comment: I assume you mean $f(0)=0$?

Comment: Can you squeeze it?

Comment: Since the function is clearly continuous elsewhere compute the limit at $0$ using the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Just Graph it using a graphing calculator and see if its continues

Answer (score 2):

From the inequality
$$
-x\leq x\sin(1/x)\leq x,
$$ 
we have 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}x\sin(1/x)=0.$$
Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=f(0)$, it follows that $f(x)$ is continous at $x=0$.

For the rest, let $x\neq 0$. The function $x\sin(1/x)$ is continuous as being the product and composition of continuous functions.

Answer (score 0):

You know it's continuous on $(0, 1]$, so all that's left is to show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x \sin (1/x) = 0$. If you can't figure out that last part, see [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~osserman/classes/21A-F12/exam1-practice-sols.pdf/).

Answer (score 0):

We show that the function of interest is continuous at $x=0$ by showing that $\lim_{x\to 0}x\sin(1/x)=0$, using a $\delta-\epsilon$ proof.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
0&\le|x\sin(1/x)|\\\\
&=|x|\,|\sin(1/x)|\\\\
&\le |x|\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $|x|<\delta =\epsilon$.  And we are done!