# Do we have that $f \in W^{1, 1}(0, 1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

This is a follow up to my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660633/fx-x-sin1-x-0-x-le-1-with-f0-0-is-continuous-on-0-1).

> How do I see that the function
>   $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
> x \sin(1/x) & 0 < x \le 1,\\
> 0           & x = 0
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   is continuous on $[0, 1]$?

Do we have that $f \in W^{1, 1}(0, 1)$?

Comment: Is $f'$ integrable in a neighborhood of $0$?

Answer (score 2):

As $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$, therefore $f \in L^1([0,1])$. As $f$ is differentiable everywhere but in $0$, its weak derivative exists and equals its derivative, we have
 $$ f'(x) = -\frac 1x\cos x^{-1} + \sin x^{-1} $$
which is not integrable, as 
$$ |f'(x)| \ge \frac 1{2x} $$
for $x \le \frac 14$. Therefore $f' \not\in L^1([0,1])$ and $f \not\in W^{1,1}([0,1])$.